# Can we simply consider a pseudo random number generator to be a function $f: \Bbb{Z}_n \to \Bbb{Z}_n$ for ever-increasing $n$?

Tags: randomized-algorithms, polynomial-time, randomness, random-number-generator, open-problem

On modern architectures, random number generators get seeded by the current system time as a source of randomness, which is nice because it is kind of unpredictable when a process will switch to the current process.  When this timer is in milliseconds or nanoseconds for example, you will get a good random number seed.  But the time datatype is usually a 64-bit integer, so in problems concerning randomized algorithms algorithms, can we assume that the RNG they use is simply a map $f: \Bbb{Z}/{2^{64}}\to \Bbb{Z}/{2^{64}}$?  Or must we always assume that it's $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}/2^n$ where $n$ is the word size, could be ${64}$?

I think the first version lends itself to better analytical methods because there is then really only a finite number of possible RNG's at ("inductive stage") $n$, where inductive stage simply refers to the obvious method of induction you could then employ on $n$ in proofs concerning randomized algorithms.  For example, it is still an open problem whether or not any randomized polynomial-time algorithm can be derandomized into a deterministic polynomial-time algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single answer to this.  It all depends on the PRNG.

The most common case is that the seed is of fixed length, i.e., it is in $\{0,1\}^c$ for some constant $c$ (e.g., $c=64$).  You can think of this as $\mathbb{Z}/2^c\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\{0,1\}^c$ if you prefer; they are isomorphic.

It is implementation-dependent how a PRNG is seeded.  Don't assume it is necessarily the time of day.  For instance, it might be seeded with [rdrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND), /dev/urandom, or any number of other possibilities.

I am commenting above about PRNGs in practice.  If you are more interested in theory, PRNGs can be formalized precisely in several ways.  If you are interested in theoretical foundations and asymptotics, I recommend learning about cryptographic [pseudorandom generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator), which have a precise formalization.

Comment: Thank you!  This is very interesting!